# Remove dependent variable from formula for model.matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm just learning how to deal with `model.matrix`. For example, to create out-of-sample predictions I extract the formula from my model, say it's a linear model. 
Using the function `formula(mymodel)` extracts that:

```
form <- formula(y ~ x1 + x2 * x3)
```

Now, to create predictions I need a model.matrix without my `y`. I could type that by hand:

```
X <- model.matrix(~ x1 + x2 * x3, data=out.of.sample.data)
```

However, is there a way using, for example, `update` to get rid of the left part my formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I usually do this. I'm not aware of a built-in function for this.

```
df = data.frame(y=rnorm(10), x1=rnorm(10), x2=rnorm(10), x3=rnorm(10))
mymodel = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, df)
form_vars_only = 
  formula(paste("~",strsplit(as.character(formula(mymodel)),"~")[[3]]))
```

Answer (score 8):

It can be done with `update` by setting the response variable to `NULL`:

```
form <- formula(y ~ x1 + x2 * x3)
newform <- update(form, NULL ~ .)
```